# Visual Studio 2013 client-side debugging tools: How to turn off?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2013

When you F5 a web app in **Visual Studio**, your page contains this:

[image]

I am having trouble with some javascript on a page and have the feeling that the javascript behind the vs tooling could interfere.

Is there any way to **turn this off**?

Comment: Looks like the Web Essentials logo?

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter said, the toolbar is from web essentials. Deactivating the extension removed it, and in fact did fix the problems I was experiencing.